# CocoaPods Installation issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

After installing cocoa pods to my project i am trying to open .xcworkspace file. but it is not opening and giving me following error.

[image]

Comment: I suspect it is because of the "&" character. Try to create a project with no special character and see if you can work with it from there.

Comment: @AndyIbanez Yeah you are right. special characters are causing issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andylbanez. Special characters in project name causing issue. After removing special characters it works.!!!